# Start spinner before starting process on main thread?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, cocoa-touch

I have this method:

```
-(IBAction)clickedDone; {
    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    spinner.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2, self.view.frame.size.height / 2);
    [spinner startAnimating];

    //intensive stuff here
}
```

However, the spinner doesn't have time (I presume) to start before the intensive stuff comes afterward which blocks the main thread I guess. I want to know if there's a way to get this spinner animating before the thread is blocked.  It'd be too much work to refactor my code to run the "intensive stuff" in a detached thread.  The only alternative I can think of would be to delay the "intensive stuff" for a fraction of a second in order for the spinner to start.

What do you all think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to put the expensive stuff on a second thread. Otherwise you block the interface as you say. It may be more work, but thats better than a bad user experience.

Comment: I did something similar, I just put it in a method and used `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` with about 0.1 seconds in delay, and that seemed to be enough to let it load the spinner before it started on the main beef.

Comment: @sudo that solution is probably still going to hurt you eventually. If the main thread becomes unresponsive for too long the OS will assume your app has hung and will terminate it. Since all you would need to do is add a `-performSelectorInBackground:withObject:`/`-performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` pair of calls to move your expensive work off onto another thread I think its worth doing now rather than when your users start complaining the app crashes.

Comment: @Jonah Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll try to implement, as I see it'd be for the best.

Answer (score 2):

The spinner can only spin if the main thread is not being blocked. Therefore, you have to run "intensive stuff" on a different thread. Also, in order to delay "intensive stuff", you would have to add it to the operation queue for the thread, allowing the run loop to start over. If you are already planning that, then you might as well put it on a different thread.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to add it to the view:

```
[self.view addSubview:spinner];
```

Maybe that fixes things already.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry I left that part of the code out.  It is in the original code, I just left out that and other parts during copy/paste. :)